# Сообщения без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: php, ajax

Подскажите, мне нужно отображение сообщений на сайте в реальном времени.

Получается, я просто делаю постоянный запрос к базе через ajax (setInterval) ?
Если да, то как часто надо делать запрос, чтобы ничего не подвисало : раз в секунду или сколько ? Возможно есть другие методы ?

Примеры : диалоги ВК

Comment: Изучите WebSocket.

Comment: Лучше реализовать websocket’ы для двунаправленной связи

Answer (score 0):

Если уж речь про VK зашла, то там Long Polling используется.

1. Клиент отправляет http запрос на сервер.
2. Сервер не сразу отвечает на него. Соединение висит в статусе ожидания.

   1. Если произошли какие-то изменения (ваш собеседник отправил сообщение/прочитал ваше), то сервер возвращает ответ.
   2. Если не было никаких изменений долгое время, то соединение отвеливается по таймауту. После чего клиент посылает новый запрос на сервер.

Answer (score -3):

раз 5 сек достаточно. Хотя смотря что за данные. Если котировки на бирже, то мало раз в секунду. Соответственно, если котировки, то нужно искать другое решение. А если раз в минуту послать запрос, то ничего страшного не вижу.

Comment: Плохой пример...

Comment: чем же пример плох?

Comment: А тем, что долбит постоянно. Да и вообще, прошлый век

Comment: прошлый, не прошлый, а такая реализация  ещё много где встречается. Так что минусы поставлены не справедливо. Автор вопроса явно дал понять, что не силён в данном направлении. Поэтому это для него лучший способ. Тем более не понятно, какие данные он хочет обновлять. Есть данные, которые и раз в час не нужно обновлять.

Comment: Такая реализация как минимум глупая и не правильная. Ибо есть `long pulling` раз на то пошло, а ваши интервалы и т. д., только будут убивать сервер, а вообще, лучше `websocket`, для этого и разработчики браузеров сделали специальную надстройку над `HTTP` протоколом. К тому-же, уже давным давно есть множество реализаций для работы с `websocket` и городить интервалы и постоянные долбежки сервера через аякс не разумно.

Comment: Новичку нужен быстрый ответ, а не ответ в котором он месяц будет разбираться. Я же написал, что не понятно о каких данных идёт речь. Может он свой тестовый сайт тестирует...